# Bloomberg formula to Excel from Python via Win32com

Tags: excel, python-3.x, win32com

So this is a big program where I am trying to automate many tasks but here is the line killing me. I am using Python 3.5.5 and Win32com to connect Python and Excel.

```
ws.Cells(i,j).Value = '=BDP("' + tick.lstrip().rstrip() + \
                      '";"CUST_TRR_RETURN_HOLDING_PER";' + \
                      '"CUST_TRR_Start_DT='+ (day - dt.timedelta(1)).strftime("%Y%m%d") + \
                      '";"CUST_TRR_END_DT=' + day.strftime("%Y%m%d") + \
                      '";"CUSTOM_TOTAL_RETURN_START_PRICE=' + str(round(sp,2)) + \
                      '";"CUSTOM_TOTAL_RETURN_END_PRICE=' + str(round(ep,2)) +'")'
```

So if I change the beginning to

```
ws.Cells(i,j).Value = 'f=bdp....'
```

so that it is not an Excel formula anymore, no issues everything goes to Excel  properly. I can then remove the *f* manually and the formula calculates as expected. However when I run the code as it is, I get an error saying that an exception occurred and the code stops. I tried with a simple formula `'=2*6'` and it works fine.
I also tried `Cells.Formula` instead of `Cells.Value` but I get the same issue.

This is very frustrating as it is the last part of my project. Everything before and after is functional so any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Even weirder, I just tried this and it works

```
ws.Cells(i,j).Value = 'f=BDP("' + tick.lstrip().rstrip() + \
                      '";"CUST_TRR_RETURN_HOLDING_PER";' + \
                      '"CUST_TRR_Start_DT='+ (day - dt.timedelta(1)).strftime("%Y%m%d") + \
                      '";"CUST_TRR_END_DT=' + day.strftime("%Y%m%d") + \
                      '";"CUSTOM_TOTAL_RETURN_START_PRICE=' + str(round(sp,2)) + \
                      '";"CUSTOM_TOTAL_RETURN_END_PRICE=' + str(round(ep,2)) +'")'
ws.Cells(i,j).Replace('f=', '=')
```

SO I make sure it is not a formula when I write it down, and then I make it a formula and it works fine.

Still trying to understand as this does not seem to be the best approach.

Thanks

Comment: I know some people have an issue to load the bloomber addin but this is not my issue the addin is fine...